# segmentation fault, and queue not clearing sometimes in beaglebone black debian OS

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, queue, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I use three different threads to read can messages from socket CAN raw and to write can messages to another socket CAN raw, The message read every 2 seconds are put onto queue and retrieved from queue on another thread, mutex thread functions are used, The idea is to write the CAN message every 2 seconds as read. But CAN messages are written every 0.3 millisecond by constantly retrieving from the queue. when the message is only read and put onto queue on every 2 second, so queue the message that is retrieved is not getting removed and remains stagnant in the queue. Every time I try to increase the msgsize, the program shows segmentation fault or automatically killed by the OS. How do i go about debugging this issue. please help, thank you

Comment: We can't help you without your code. Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Debug on the old method: print when message get in, and get out (and with thread information). Then add/move prints until you get near the bug. Or just use a short queue (maybe an assert and assert queue is max 5 element long (with a short test, you should find/debug the problem). Not for production (where you may get some message at same time